# VB.NET Keep TCP Connection Alive

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if i ask lot of question these days
With the following function i can successfully connect and login to a server but the problem is when it log in to server it will instantly disconnected
However when i tried to login to that server with autoit,it worked and it remains connected
Here is the function that im using in VB.NET (Its in a class)

```
Public Shared ConnectionSocket As New TcpClient
Public Shared Stream As NetworkStream

Public Shared Function Connect(ByRef IP As String, ByRef Port As Integer)
    ConnectionSocket.Connect(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(IP), Port)
    Stream = ConnectionSocket.GetStream
    ConnectionSocket.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, True)
    Dim RecievedBytes(ConnectionSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    Dim Temp As New List(Of Byte())
    Dim Temp2 As New List(Of Byte())
    Dim Data As Byte()
    Dim Final As Byte()
    Temp.Add({&H10, &H1})
    Temp.Add({&H0})
    Temp.Add({&H97, &H2F})
    Temp.Add(UserPacket)
    Temp.Add(PasswordPacket)
    Temp.Add({&H0})
    Temp.Add({&H1})
    Temp.Add({&H0})
    Temp.Add({&H77, &HD1, &HCA, &HC3, &HEB, &H3A, &H2, &H81, &HDB, &HA, &H51})
    Temp.Add({&H0})
    Temp.Add({&H69, &H6E, &H74, &H6C})
    Temp.Add({&H0, &H0, &H0})
    Temp.Add(StringToByte(My.Settings.BotUsername))
    Temp.Add({&H0})
    Data = Temp.SelectMany(Function(x) x).ToArray()
    Temp2.Add(IntegerToByte(Data.Length - 4))
    Temp2.Add(Data)
    Final = Temp2.SelectMany(Function(x) x).ToArray()

    Stream.Write(Final, 0, Final.Length)

    While True

        Try
            Stream.Read(RecievedBytes, 0, CInt(ConnectionSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End While
End Function
```

And I call this function on MainForm_Load
If also posting autoit code helps,tell me to add it in here

Comment: Side note: instead of making `Temp As List(Of Byte())`, just make it a `List(Of Byte)` and use `AddRange` to add multiple bytes to it.  Then you can just call `Temp.ToArray()` to get the full byte array.

Comment: Another side note: why are you using `ByRef` parameters?

Comment: @JonSkeet Because i don't know the difference,but it makes no sense in this situation,both works well

Comment: @Shahriyar: Now would be a *very* good time to learn about such an important part of the language you're using. (Yes, it's harmless here - but it's fundamental...)

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted here appears like it would cause the client to close the socket.  So, the likely problem is not that the client is closing it, but that the server is.  If that's the case, it may be because the data you are sending is different, in some way.

Comment: @StevenDoggart WowOw ! You were right,There was a 4F that needed to be 4B :| not it works like a charm,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the code you posted here appears like it would cause the client to close the socket. So, the likely problem is not that the client is closing it, but that the server is. If that's the case, it may be because the data you are sending is different, in some way.

Comment: Now i have another question,is there any way to use While True in that function without getting whole program freezed ?because when i use While true and get the server answers the main form doesnt appears

Comment: No, not in that function.  Well, I guess I shouldn't say it *that* emphatically.  You *can*, but only if you are willing to call `Application.DoEvents`, and you absolutely should never be willing to do *that*.  The proper way to do it would be to start a separate thread, and then do the loop in the other thread, or use the async methods in the stream, such as `BeginRead`.  Either way, it's a bit more complicated, but please, please, please don't call `DoEvents`.  I regret even mentioning it.